# Laravel 4 - ReflectionException Class / does not exist

Tags: reflection, laravel-4

When attempting to load the page, I'm getting the error that the ReflectionException Class / does not exist (open: /var/www/laravel_guestbook/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerInspector.php), could use some insight on what is causing this error.

Furthermore, I've also run 'composer dump-autoload' at the root of my project folder to no avail.

**routes.php**

```
Route::controller('EntriesController', '/');
```

**Entry.php**

```
<?php
class Entry extends Eloquent {

   /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'entries';
}
?>
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel 4 Guestbook</title>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach ($entries as $entry)
        <p>{{ $entry->comment }}</p>
        <p>Posted on {{ $entry->created_at->format('M jS, Y') }} by 
           <a href="mailto:{{ $entry->email }}"> {{ $entry->username}}</a>
        </p><hr>
    @endforeach

    <form action="/" method="post">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="frmName" value="" size="30" maxlength="50"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="frmEmail" value="" size="30" maxlength="100"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Comment</td>
                <td><input textarea name="frmComment" row="5" cols="30"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
                    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**EntriesController.php**

```
<?php

class EntriesController extends BaseController {

    # Handles "GET /" request
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('home')
                ->with('entries', Entry::all());
    }

    # Handles "POST /"  request
    public function postIndex()
    {
        // get form input data
        $entry = array(
            'username' => Input::get('frmName'),
            'email'    => Input::get('frmEmail'),
            'comment'  => Input::get('frmComment'),
        );

        // save the guestbook entry to the database
        Entry::create($entry);

        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's suppose to be:

```
Route::controller('/', 'EntriesController');
```

Answer (score 4):

If your naming is correct but you still get this type of error do a

```
composer update
```

This command will refresh your composer autoload files (among others).

Comment: `composer update` will check/download and update all dependencies in project (which may take some time or not necessary), if needed just generate new autoload file just use `composer dumpautoload` / `composer dump-autoload` https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload

Answer (score 1):

In my case the name of the file was PostController.php, but inside I had

```
class Post extends \BaseController {
```

Instead of

```
class PostController extends \BaseController {
```

I had to rename the file as "php artisan generate:controller " command requires the word controller to be specified.